Initializing opus encoder crashes with illegal instruction error
I have an application that captures and streams audio over a websocket connection. Before sending over websocket, audio data is encoded using OPUS. This application works in most of the devices, where in some devices it crashes with the below error in windows event viewer.
Faulting application name: AudioClient.exe, version: 1.0.0.6, time stamp: 0x654b75be
Faulting module name: AudioClient.exe, version: 1.0.0.6, time stamp: 0x654b75be
Exception code: 0xc000001d
Fault offset: 0x000d042d
Faulting process id: 0x2684
Faulting application start time: 0x01da1bd5fccdbe9e
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\AudioClient.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\AudioClient.exe
Report Id: 72dee3cc-e5ac-476d-bb0e-a5a383f164e7
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID: Windows cannot access the file for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program because of this error.
File: The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.
User Action
Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again. If the file still cannot be accessed and It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be contacted. It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt, type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or computer hardware vendor for further assistance.
Tried the approach mentioned in the event viewer, which didn't work. Using Windows Error Reporting, I was able to capture the dump and found that error occurs in the below segment of code with 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction exception,
int err = 0;        
OpusEncoder* encoder = opus_encoder_create(Sample_rate , channel_count , app_type , &err);

DATA: Sample_rate = 48000, channel_count = 1, app_type = OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO
Not able to find why this line crashes in some devices alone. Any suggestions to address the issue are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
